Azure Container App revisions - prevent rolling update?
I want to create new revisions for Azure Container Apps based on new images. Now, some of these images will have database migrations, i.e. breaking changes, some won't. For the ones which won't I will just copy the revision with the updated image - fine. But what about the ones for which I do not want rolling updates? (Short downtime is fine.)
I can deactivate the previous/current revision, but when I then copy it again, it seems that both will be activated (also suddenly all my other previous inactive revisions appear to be gone)? I could scale it to zero I guess, but that seems rather hacky. Is there a straightforward way, am I missing something?
(I plan to update those apps from a remote Jenkins/Gitlab pipeline).

I was thinking what if before deploying a new revision that includes breaking changes, deactivate the current revision. This will ensure that it does not receive any traffic during the deployment of the new revision. After deactivating the current revision, you can copy it to create a new revision with the updated image which will be created based on the configuration of the deactivated revision.  Once the new revision is ready and you are confident that it can handle traffic, you can activate it. This way you can control when the new revision goes live, what do you say?

Afaik, Azure Container Apps inherently support revision-based updates- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/revisions-manage?tabs=bash

As I wrote above: the irritating thing to me is that it appears that when I deactivate the latest revision, copy it, then both (the deactivated and the new revision) get activated..?

which revision mode are you using? I was checking MS docs and as per that I feel single revision mode is better suited for your requirement as it prevents rolling updates by deactivating the current revision automatically when a new one is activated. Could you just try these steps and let me know - Deactivate the current revision explicitly before deploying a new one. deploy the revision but do not activate it immediately. Complete your database migrations before activating the new revision. Once migrations are complete, activate the new revision to route traffic to it.

az containerapp revision set-mode
az containerapp revision deactivate
az containerapp update

az containerapp revision activate As per MS if on single revision mode, the old revision will be automatically deactivated. If it is happening otherwise then I would recommend you raise a MS case.

Running in single revision mode. Tried with az containerapp update - again 2 problems: this a) implicitly seems to activate the revision again (after deactivating it before) (in fact 2: the old one and the new one) b) updating the image does not update the image of the init container, only the application image itself?
